# Cant insert data from dropdown menu in table from thymeleaf but can in MySQL manually

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

On the page, I have a form that, among other things, in addition to fields for entering amounts, notes, and dates, also has a drop-down menu that allows the user to choose one item from the list. That dropdown menu is populated from the database and that works fine. Now, when user choose one item from the list and click on save button to insert his choices into database, that field is null in the table, other fields are saved fine but that field from dropdown menu is not saved, its NULL. But, I can go in MySQL and manually assign category to that field, see picture below.

Its like this after user click on save:

[image]

But I can assignee manually that field from MySQL, as you can see:

[image]

This is thymeleaf code:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/api/transaction/saveTransaction/{walletId} (walletId=${id})}"
      th:object="${transaction}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{amount}" placeholder="Enter amount" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">

    <input type="text" th:field="*{note}" placeholder="Enter note" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
    <input type="date" th:field="*{date}" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
    <select class="form-control" id="dropOperator">
        <option value="0">Select category</option>
        <option th:each="categories : ${categories}" th:value="${categories.name}"
                th:text="${categories.name}"></option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2"> Save Wallet</button>
</form>
```

This is controller to save that form:

```
   @PostMapping("/saveTransaction/{walletId}")
   public String saveTransaction(@PathVariable(value = "walletId") long walletId, 
   @ModelAttribute("transaction") Transaction transaction) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();

    Wallet wallet = walletService.getWalletById(walletId);


    transaction.setWallet(wallet);
    transactionService.saveTransaction(transaction);
    return "redirect:/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/" + userId;
}
```

This is controller that show form:

```
    @GetMapping("/showNewTransactionForm/{id}")
public String showNewTransactionForm(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Transaction transaction, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();
    model.addAttribute("userId", userId);

    model.addAttribute("transaction", transaction);
    List<Category> categories = categoryService.getAllCategories();
    model.addAttribute("categories", categories);

    return "new_transaction";

}
```

This is `category` entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "category_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "category_name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
private List<Transaction> transactions;
```

This is `transaction` entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "transaction_id")
private Long id;

private double amount;

private String note;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_name", referencedColumnName = "category_name")
private Category category;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="wallet_id", nullable=false)
private Wallet wallet;
```

Any advice what I can try? I had an error for that field that says `Cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails` but I fixed it somehow and now there is no errors at all, just field is not saved into database, but, as I said I can insert it manually successful in MySQL.

Comment: You don't have a mapping for `select`  try add `th:field="*{category}"`  to you page `select`

Comment: Now I'm getting error like this after submit:

`1 errors<EOL>Field error in object 'transaction' on field 'category': rejected value [Shopping]; codes [typeMismatch.transaction.category,typeMismatch.category,typeMismatch.com.budgettracker.demo.userProfile.models.Category,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:`

Comment: `codes [transaction.category,category]; arguments []; default message [category]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.budgettracker.demo.userProfile.models.Category' for property 'category'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'Shopping'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Shopping"]]`

Comment: When i put `categories.id` instead of name its work, but i want to show user names of categories no IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try writing that, because
th: field is equivalent to
`th:name` + `th:value`

```
<select class="form-control" id="dropOperator">
    <option value="0">Select category</option>
    <option th:each="categories : ${categories}" th:value="${categories.id}"
            th:text="${categories.name}" th:name="*{category.name}"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: I forgot to update my comment, I solved it like you in your example, thank you anyway